# Parsing nested collections in backbone

Tags: backbone.js

Hi i have a nested collection.

```
{"Categories":[{},{},{}],"Preference":[{},{},{}],"Users":[{},{},{}]}
```

Now what i what is to pass Categories to another collection, preference to another collection and users to another collection too. Is it still confusing? I've read that you can do this on a model but will it do the work? Any ideas?

Comment: Pretty confusing, How did you manage to add 3 different types of collection into one? Could you add some JSON response sent from server for `Collection.fetch()` and explain which key goes to which collection.

Comment: no sorry. what i mean was the response is like the one i posted above.

Answer (score 2):

If you have control over your backend, what you probably want to do is split the retrieval of the collection into three different Ajax calls:

```
var Categories = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "/categories"
});
var Preferences = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "/preferences"
});
var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "/users"
});
var categories = new Categories();
categories.fetch();
...
```

If you can't change the routes on your server for some reason, then you can manually create the models by passing the arrays into the constructor:

```
var categories = new Categories(data["Categories"]);
```

If the data is in JSON format you can use jQuery to parse into a Javascript object:
`jQuery.parseJSON(data);`